# Two key values in HKEY_USERS in registry entry for the same user

Tags: c#, registry

I am having two accounts in HKEY_USERS in registry entry for the same user.

These are:

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1012

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1014

The problem comes when I fetch the value for the current user using Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey() method.
It fetches the value from HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1012 while HKEY_CURRENT_USER is mapped(or in sync) with HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1014.
So the actual values are not fetched. Can someone please help me out in this context as why two accounts exists in registry for the same user and how i can map(or do sync) for HKEY_CURRENT_USER with

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1014.

My code is as follows:

```
    string strKeyIESettings = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges";
        string valRange1 = "", valRange2 = "", valRange3 = "", valRange4 = "";
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey keyIESettings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(strKeyIESettings))
        {
            foreach (string subkey_name in keyIESettings.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey subkey = keyIESettings.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                {
                    switch (subkey_name)
                    {
                        case "Range1" :
                            if (subkey.GetValue(":Range") != null)
                            {
                                valRange1 = subkey.GetValue(":Range").ToString();
                            }                                
                            break;

                        case "Range2" :
                            if (subkey.GetValue(":Range") != null)
                            {
                                valRange2 = subkey.GetValue(":Range").ToString();
                            }                                
                            break;

                        case "Range3":
                            if (subkey.GetValue(":Range") != null)
                            {
                                valRange3 = subkey.GetValue(":Range").ToString();
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Range4":
                            if (subkey.GetValue(":Range") != null)
                            {
                                valRange4 = subkey.GetValue(":Range").ToString();
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (valRange1 == "10.237.24.165" && valRange2 == "10.237.24.166" && valRange3 == "10.237.24.167" && valRange4 == "10.237.24.168")
        {
            flagIESettings = true;
        }
```

I have to fetch these values as my application pre-requisite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for the above question. It is as follows:
I am having two accounts in HKEY_USERS in registry entry for the same user because I have installed ASP.NET. 
One account is for ASP.NET 
and Other one is my current user.
It is always the case when ASP.NET is installed on a user's machine, there are two accounts for the current user in the registry. And one is mapped with HKCU.

Thanks

Comment: No. Those two keys represent two different user accounts.

Comment: Thanks David. But I have researched this topic. You are right that two keys represents two user accounts but as ASP.NET is installed on one's machine, a user account named 'ASPNET' is automatically added. So the second key represents ASPNET account.

Comment: Exactly. That's a different user.